# window.location.replace occasionally not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've setup a Bootstrap Dropdown where I get the language to translate my site to, Append the URL and then reload the page.

It seems to work fine for the first set of translations i.e en|es, But if I go to reset it back or change it to another language, It just doesn't reload. Not too sure why, hoping someone can help. Or provide an alternate way of doing this?

I suspect it's something to do with the stripping of the URL?

```html
<div class="dropdown translate__dropdown d-inline-block">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle chosen__language" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img src="http://mastersite.loc/assets/images/flags/fr.png" alt="en">
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a data-value="en|en" data-lang="en" class="dropdown-item language__select" href="#">
      <img src="http://mastersite.loc/assets/images/flags/en.png" alt="en">
    </a>
    <a data-value="en|fr" data-lang="fr" class="dropdown-item language__select" href="#">
      <img src="http://mastersite.loc/assets/images/flags/fr.png" alt="fr">
    </a>
    <a data-value="en|es" data-lang="es" class="dropdown-item language__select" href="#">
      <img src="http://mastersite.loc/assets/images/flags/es.png" alt="es">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
// Language Settings....
if ($(".language__select").length) {
  $('.language__select').on('click', function() {
    var url = stripUrl(window.location.href);
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    var new_url = url + '?/#googtrans(' + value + ')';
    var language = $(this).data('lang');
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    // Send Ajax Call To Change Lang...
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/set-language',
      data: {
        language: language,
        _token: token
      },
      success: function() {
        // Now Reload page using New URL...
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.replace(new_url);
        }, 1000)
      }
    })
    return false;
  })

  function stripUrl(urlToStrip) {
    let stripped = urlToStrip.split('?')[0];
    stripped = stripped.split('&')[0];
    stripped = stripped.split('#')[0];
    return stripped;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the web console?

Comment: Hi @Sasha none whatsoever :/

Comment: do a `console.log(new_url)` in the success function and see if that gets called and if the URL is correct

Comment: try `console.log(new_url);` just above your window.location.replace and see what happens

Comment: Try this:`var new_url = url + '?/#googtrans(' + value + ')';
  new_url = encodeURI(new_url); ........`

Comment: @Rk003 that's what I wanted to point out (bad url encoding) and then give the `encodeURI(new_url)` suggestion.

Comment: Why use ajax in the first place if you redirect the user after the request anyway? Can't you just submit to the page and use an HTTP redirect from there?

Comment: It logs the new URL, But doesn't reload / replace in the browser. I can log the new_url but still no luck, have also removed the AJAX call - This just stores a session of the users chosen language

Comment: If `console.log(new_url)` above the `window.replace` call isn't showing, perhaps the ajax call is failing?  Have you tried using the `complete` or `error` callbacks on the ajax call?

Comment: did you check weather its going into success or your ajax call is failinig?

Comment: I think the browser is interpereting the # as an go to ID so is not reloading, but trying to go to it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
window.open(new_url,"_self")
```

or

```
location.href = new_url
```